# Ag-grid throws error: this.gridOptionsWrapper.getNodeChildDetailsFunc is not a function

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have updated my ag-grid to version 24.1.0 but in chrome console it throws errors which says: this.gridOptionsWrapper.getNodeChildDetailsFunc is not a function and no columns is visible in grid.

Downgrade to 24.0.0 does not work either.
If I downgrade to 23.2.0 it works.
Anyone else have this type of issue?

I can't understand how to fix it.
There should be a ag-grid under the "Refresh" button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: GridOptionsWrapper was [removed](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/commit/53d6dd2135b898b07c2eb822e22b6ac3676428e6) for v29. The ticket number was _AG-7603 Delete GridOptionsWrapper_, not public on the [AG Grid Changelog](https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error `this.gridOptionsWrapper.getIsGroupOpenByDefaultFunc is not a function` and it was because I had a mismatch in my versions of `ag-grid-[community/enterprise/react]`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and after some trial and error I found that it was because I had set `[modules]="AllModules"` on my grid instance. I was importing AllModules from enterprise and I think that caused an issue; I am guessing the enterprise version is missing `getNodeChildDetailsFunc` which community presumably has. I am using angular but I don't believe that matters in this case.

Configuration with the issue:

```js
// typescript
import { AllModules } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
```

```html
<!-- Corresponding HTML -->
<ag-grid-angular
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
      [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      [modules]="AllModules">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Configuration that worked:

```html
<ag-grid-angular
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
      [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
</ag-grid-angular>
```